Programmatically access Chrome-corrected HTML
I need to correct a bunch of incorrect HTML. This HTML has worked in user's browsers in the past, so I would like to just use the corrections from one of these browsers.
I'm able to programmatically load HTML in Chrome through C# using Selenium and ChromeDriver. The window opens and shows the corrected HTML in the developer tools.
However, I am so far unable to access the corrected HTML through C# (driver.PageSource just shows the old HTML). Even going into the Console in Chrome and executing document.documentElement.outerHTML returns the old HTML, while the corrected version is loaded and is shown in the "Elements" tab in the dev-tools.
Does anyone know how to access the corrected HTML programmatically?
I have tried:
in C#:
driver.PageSource 

in js:
document.documentElement.outerHTML 

and
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
                var correctedHTML = serializer.serializeToString(document);
                return correctedHTML;


FYI, python's BeautifulSoup + html5lib does exactly what you want.
